# jsPlumb and jQuery.PanZoom dragging issue

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I used jquery.panzoom plugin in order to zoom and pan jsPlumb diagrams and every things is working find but when i zoom and drag an element this one goes far away from the pointer!
Does someone facing the same issue? can some one help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

see this
http://jsfiddle.net/a4v2guvt/

```
$panzoom.on('panzoomzoom', function (e, panzoom, scale) {
    jsPlumb.setZoom(scale);
});
```

Comment: This is not working the way it should. If I zoom in/our and drag to the stage it doesn't go to the right position

Answer (score 0):

To fix this i used jQueryUI/draggable instead of builtin one:

```
var currentScale = 1;
$container.find(".diagram .item").draggable({
start: function(e){
  var pz = $container.find(".panzoom");
  //we need current scale factor to adjust coordinates of dragging element
  currentScale = pz.panzoom("getMatrix")[0];
  $(this).css("cursor","move");
  pz.panzoom("disable");//disable panzoom to avoid double offset
},
drag:function(e,ui){
  //fix scale issue
  ui.position.left = ui.position.left/currentScale;
  ui.position.top = ui.position.top/currentScale;
  if($(this).hasClass("jsplumb-connected"))
  {
    plumb.repaint($(this).attr('id'),ui.position);
  }
},
stop: function(e,ui){
  var nodeId = $(this).attr('id');
  plumb.repaint(nodeId,ui.position);
  $(this).css("cursor","");
  //enable panzoom back
  $container.find(".panzoom").panzoom("enable");
}
});
```

Look at [this demo](http://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/vXYomB)